# what is the result of pointer of a type & valiable

Tags: c++

I am trying to understand a code. But I could not understand the last line?
What is the result of `*(uint8_t*)&b[8]=`?

```
typedef uint8_t a;
uint8_t *b = new uint8_t[100];
RPC_flags_t c;
c=0U;
*((a*)&(b[8]))=c;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an obfuscation of `b[8] = c;`

- `&(b[8])` is `b + 8` (or the address of `b[8]`)
- `(a*)&(b[8])` is a cast to `a*` so `uint8_t*` which is already the type of `b + 8`, so it is equivalent to `&(b[8])`
- `*((a*)&(b[8]))` is `*&(b[8])` so `b[8]`.

Comment: so why he wrote this line so complicated? what is the advantages?

Comment: @ZahraBoroujeni: if `a*` was not of the same type `b` (as `uint32_t` for example), it would allow to write an `uint32_t` at the address of `b + 8` (I would wrote in that case something like `*static_cast<uint32_t*>(b + 8) = c`)

Answer (score 2):

It take the address of `b[8]`, cast it to a pointer to type `a`, and then assign the content of `c` to the memory it points to.